# What are the strengths of OpenSolaris compared to Linux?

Tags: linux, solaris, opensolaris

Please try to answer in these areas:

- For what kind of usage is OpenSolaris more suited than Linux?
- What are the useful OpenSolaris features that Linux lacks?

Personal experiences are welcomed, but please don't start a flame war. Strengths of Linux over OpenSolaris are beyond this topic.

*(For Linux, I'm thinking of something like Ubuntu or Fedora, but not RHEL, if that matters.)*

*(I have used Linux servers for a long time but have never used Solaris, if that matters.)*

Comment: Apparently DTrace and ZFS are two of the unique features of Solaris. Please comment on their usefulness.

Comment: Similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/110679/are-there-any-advantages-to-using-opensolaris-over-linux-other-than-zfs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ZFS filesystem in OpenSolaris was the deciding factor over Linux/BSD for me when I recently built a file server.

Some compelling ZFS features for me were:

- RAID-Z redundancy
- Data integrity checksums fundamental to the design
- Snapshots
- Simple command line tools

Sure, ZFS can be bolted on to Linux with FUSE but in OpenSolaris it is standard and (so far for me) rock solid.

Comment: Current versions of ZFS also support deduplication, which can save a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 2):

Also:

- [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) support, a very powerful tracing framework.
- Availability of [Solaris Containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_Containers), an os-level virtualization technology.
- ZFS

Comment: Update: Linux also has its own containers (LXC)

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means a expert with OpenSolaris or Linux however,  I do know hardware support on most distros of Linux is far greater than Unix(s), and most older hardware is less likely to work.

Comment: Most older hardware on OpenSolaris and other unices, you mean?